# how to print a list that is in a dictionary, as a string in python? And how to edit the list's elements?

Tags: python, list, class, dictionary, key-value

I have a class that has a dictionary attribute. The dictionary has song titles as its key and a list containing artist, genre and playCount like this:

```
class library:
def __init__(self,library):
    self.library={}
def addSong(self,title,artist,genre,playCount):
    self.library[title]=[artist,genre,playCount]
```

The playCount is an integer. How do I add a 1 to the playCount element without changing any of the other elements. Do I make a new function for it or can I do it without making a function?. Also how can I make a function to print the keys and values of the dictionary as a string like this:

```
artist, title (genre), playCount
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you just want to increment `playCount` every time you pass an existing title to `addSong`, right?

You can put in an if-else condition in `addSong` to check if `title` is in `self.library` or not and if it exists, then just increment the last element of value of key `title` by `playCount`.

Also, to print, it's just a matter of assigning items in their correct positions:

```
class library:
    def __init__(self):
        self.library = {}
    
    def addSong(self, title, artist, genre, playCount=1):
        if title in self.library:
            self.library[title][-1] += playCount
        else:
            self.library[title] = [artist, genre, playCount]
            
    def get_song_data(self, title):
        if title in self.library:
            x = self.library[title] + [title]
            return "{0}, {3} ({1}), {2}".format(*x)

lib = library()
```

Output:

```
lib.addSong('Easy on Me','Adele','ballad',10)
print(lib.get_song_data('Easy on Me'))         # Adele, Easy on Me (ballad), 10

lib.addSong('Easy on Me','Adele','ballad',2)
print(lib.get_song_data('Easy on Me'))         # Adele, Easy on Me (ballad), 12

lib.addSong('Easy on Me','Adele','ballad')
print(lib.get_song_data('Easy on Me'))         # Adele, Easy on Me (ballad), 13
```